# Eclipse "Java was started but returned exit code=1" with OpenJDK

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install eclipse(`eclipse jee oxygen 4.7`) in my system(`64 bit`). Unfortunately i don't have java JDK and JRE. I'm left out with only OpenJDK 11.0.1. Is there any way to configure eclipse with OpenJDK. Below is my `eclipse.ini`

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170511-1520
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Oracle\OpenJDK 11.0.1\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
--permit-illegal-access
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 4.7 was released in 2017 doesn't support Java 11 which was released in 2018.

Either downgrade to Java 8 or use a newer Eclipse version that supports Java 11. See [Eclipse/Installation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.7_.28Oxygen.29) wiki for further information.

Comment: I have OpenJDK `9.0.4`,`10.0.1`,`11.0.1`,`12` & `13`. Does any of this helps?

Comment: @Crazy2crack You could try OpenJDK 9 and see if it works but do note that Java 9 is no longer supported. Using Eclipse 4.11 with Java 11 would be a better idea due to Java 11 being LTS.